# Simple <Grid> with 2 Columns & 2 Objects

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

Hi have a simple grid containing 2 objects, one in each column :

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Column="0" />
   <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Column="1" />

</Grid>
```

What I want : When setting "Visibility = Collapsed" of either Red or Blue rectangle the other takes all the remaining room.

Can I do that with a Grid control?

Thanks

Comment: You can do that easily with other panel say `StackPanel` or `DockPanel`.

Comment: Are you looking for a `WPF` or a `Silverlight` solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be much easy with other panels like `StackPanel` or `DockPanel`.

But in case you are interested only in Grid approach, you can **use `DataTrigger` to see if other rectangle is `Collapsed` then set `Grid.ColumnSpan` to `2` for visible rectangle**.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="blueRectangle">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility,
                                ElementName=redRectangle}" Value="Collapsed">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="redRectangle">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility, 
                                 ElementName=blueRectangle}" Value="Collapsed">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That's a much better answer!  kudos Rohit

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention I was using Silverlight (DataTrigger are not available).  Guess I will have to do that in the code.  But I like your idea, I'll mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a cheap trick, but it does work:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Column="1" />

    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: And yeah, I know that the rectangles do not actually resize.  But I do not think you can do that with Grids unless you:  Create properties that will return appropriate widths depending on the desired state, and bind the widths of the columns to these properties.  But I have built a few interfaces using this technique and it quickly gets out of hand, so I would recommend not going there...